# LINQ to SQL queries return stale results until SubmitChanges called

Tags: linq-to-sql

Consider this little piece of code using LINQ-to-SQL, using a Users table with a FirstName field:

```
var dataContext = /* get the database context */;

var user = dataContext.Users.First();
user.FirstName = "Jason";
var countOfUsersNamedJason = dataContext.Users.Count(u => u.FirstName == "Jason");
```

I would expect that `countOfUsersNamedJason` would be non-zero since I just changed the name of a user to that. However, it's still zero. It seems when another query is done against the underlying database (via `dataContext.Users`) that query is submitted to the DB and only the *submitted* data is considered. Indeed, a `dataContext.SubmitChanges()` makes my query behave as expected.

In the code I'm maintaining, I further act upon the result of that query and make other changes in other rows in the database. I expect the changes to be in one single transaction, so my plan was to have just a single `SubmitChanges()` at the every end. So:

1. Is there a way to convince LINQ-to-SQL to make queries against unsubmitted data in any way that isn't terribly error-prone? I no doubt could write code using `dataContext.GetChangeSet()` but that'll be a mess.
2. If the answer to #1 is no, what's the best practice here? When doing a transaction that makes changes, is the best practice always to create a `DbTransaction` for the `DataContext`, and allow various helper methods to call `SubmitChanges()` freely?